# Vertical dots in a tree with forest

Tags: forest

I am writing a paper about the collatz conjecture, and I want to show a diagram, but I don't know how to add ellipses to the tree.

```
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{forest} for tree={
    edge path={\noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}] (\forestOve{\forestove{@parent}}{name}.parent anchor) -- +(0,-12pt)-| (\forestove{name}.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};}
}

[1
    [2
        [4
            [8
                [16
                    [32
                        [64
                            [128
                                [256]
                            ]
                            [21
                                [42]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                    [5
                        [10
                            [20
                                [40]
                            ]
                            [3
                                [6]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]

\end{forest}
```

[image]

I want the ellipses to be where the red rectangles are, if possible

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is just to add them to the terminal nodes directly. By using `align=center` you can use linebreaks inside nodes. I've also made all content math, which simplifies the code slightly.

I've removed your path code which gave errors and doesn't seem to do much.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={math content,align=center}
[1
    [2
        [4
            [8
                [16
                    [32
                        [64
                            [128
                                [256\\\vdots]
                            ]
                            [21
                                [42\\\vdots]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                    [5
                        [10
                            [20
                                [40\\\vdots]
                            ]
                            [3
                                [6\\\vdots]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: When I add this, the ellipses appear inline with the numbers and not below them. the linebreaks dont seem to work. The new line appears above the number instead of below. Edit: Nevermind, it works, thank you

Comment: @AdamZaidi you need `align = center `.